# Generar elementos dinámicos JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html5

Que tal estan? Espero puedan ayudarme.

Tengo un div que dentro de el tiene varios campos de entrada de un formulario.
Lo que deseo es que al darle click en un botón. Pueda duplicarse ese div que ya tengo, exactamente igual, con todos esos input que lo componen.
He podido generar inputs dinámicamente, pero necesito que se duplique es el div con todos sus elementos hijo.

Espero puedan ayudarme.

Comment: Has intentado algo?

Comment: Hola. He podido generar input dinámicamente. Pero no sé cómo duplicar todo el div con sus input internos

Comment: Agrega eso a tu pregunta por favor

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Puedes utilizar el método *clone*() de jQuery. *clone* lo que hace es, tal y como la propia palabra indica, clonar todo el HTML que hay en el selector usado.

En tu ejemplo, si quieres clonar el div al tocar el botón y añadirlo en el body (o donde quieras, solo tienes que especificarlo en el appendTo), sería:

```
$('#idBoton').click(function(){
     ('#idDivAClonar').clone().appendTo("body");
});
```

Saludos

Comment: Hola! Excelente tu ejemplo funciona correctamente. El error que me muestra ahora es que cada click me duplica el mismo div. Por ejemplo; le doy click me aparece una vez, le vuelvo a dar click me aparece cuatro veces, le vuelvo a dar click, me aparece ocho veces. Lo que necesito es que con cada click se genere el div solo una vez. Cómo podría hacer?

Comment: Para ello necesitaría ver todo el código para poder sacar una conclusión, así no puedo... Gracias!

Answer (score 0):

Para duplicar cualquier elemento de tu HTML puedes utilizar la función `.clone()`, por ejemplo:

```
$(document).on('click', '#boton', function() {
    $('#elemento').clone().appendTo('body');
});
```

En este caso clonamos el elemento `#elemento` en el `body` cuando hacemos clic sobre el botón `#boton`.